# Benefit of developing managed package in a scratch org with namespace

Tags: managed-package, salesforcedx, lightning-web-components, aura, scratch-org

Why should I develop my managed package in scratch orgs that have a namespace? As opposed to having no namespace.

As far I can overlook it only a handful metadata seem to need a namespace prefix. For example, Aura components need prefixes to reference field. But if I just LWC...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of namespaced orgs is so that you can develop changes to your namespaced package without risking hosing your packaging org (at least, it reduces the probability). Add to that 2GP (Second Generation Packaging) with namespaces, and you can break your monolithic application into byte-sized pieces that can be developed and upgraded independently of each other. If you've ever had a project large enough for this to matter--and I have worked on such a beast--you would appreciate the beauty of being able to create smaller, more manageable chunks that can independently developed by multiple developers with less risk of overwriting changes.

While it's true that a decent number of metadata types don't need namespaces to work correctly, the natural assumption is that you want to have your metadata in a repository as your Source of Truth. This brings some challenges to the table. For example, when you retrieve metadata from your packaging org, the namespaces will naturally appear in your repository, including custom labels, Visualforce merge fields, and so on. When you deploy non-namespaced components to the packaging org from the repository, the code in your repository will no longer match your packaging org's actual metadata.

Also, just as an aside, you can't use LWC *everywhere*, at least not yet, so if you need Aura, you still need namespaces. And while some ISVs, etc out there have built tools that support translating to/from namespace-aware code and metadata, it would be far easier to not have to depend on such tools to begin with. Finally, I'd like to say that while DX and 2GP still offers some particular challenges to some types of apps, it is quickly reaching a point where it should be usable for just about everyone. We're even in the process of transitioning our Unlimited Edition org to 2GP, something that wasn't possible a year ago, and yet is now within reach. If we can do it, most other projects should be able to, too.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't already develop your managed package directly in your namespaced packaging org, with explicit namespace references in your metadata, you probably do not need to. They are required for that purpose, since metadata with explicit namespace references can't be pushed into ordinary non-namespaced scratch orgs.

Namespaced scratch orgs can be useful testing tools because you can see how your code behaves in a namespaced context, if you're doing things like dynamic SOQL. That doesn't mean you should use them as the main development locale, though, and of course the namespaced org *doesn't* represent a customer environment where you have a package boundary and unmanaged metadata outside it - so the utility can also be deceptive.

Most metadata works well in non-namespaced contexts, sometimes with a bit of extra logic to add a namespace prefix where needed if the code should be running in a namespaced or managed context.

Plug: Salesforce.org's open source [CumulusCI](https://github.com/SFDO-Tooling/CumulusCI) build toolchain offers extensive support for managing metadata that can be deployed cleanly into both namespaced and non-namespaced orgs; I'm on the release engineering team there. The open source Nonprofit Success Pack and EDA projects are both great examples of managed packages developed primarily in non-namespaced scratch orgs.